# Crontab error "No crontab for root"

Tags: cron

when I write `crontab -e` command in terminal,

I get this error message:

```
no crontab for root - using an empty one 888
```

I don't know what '888' is meaning?

Config file of crontab /etc/crontab:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
58 * * * * root cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
52 0 * * * root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
46 0 * * 7 root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
9 5 28 * * root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: The file edited by crontab -e and /etc/crontab are different files. http://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it

Answer (score 10):

Your `crontab` editor has been switched to `ed`. To exit `ed`, press <kbd>Q</kbd> and subsequently <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will quit the `ed` editor.

If you would like to change your `crontab` editor back to `nano` use:

```
sudo select-editor
```

This also might be helpful:

```
EDITOR=nano crontab -e
```

Answer (score 9):

That's the number of characters in the default file. Ubuntu creates an 'empty' crontab file with a lot of comments showing how to use it.

```
crontab -e 
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command
"/tmp/crontab.vILdXR/crontab" 22L, 888C
```

Comment: @lain I can't open this file ?