# Crontab -e command not working properly

Tags: 14.04, cron

First time I ran `crontab -e` it asked me to choose text editor. However I canceled command. When I run it again this is the output:

```
$ crontab -e
no crontab for root - using an empty one
888
```

How do I reset it? How do I make it ask me for text editor again?

I reinstalled (`apt-get remove cron && apt-get update && apt-get install cron`) cron but the issue is still here.

Comment: Your crontab editor appears to have been set to `ed` - see [Crontab error “No crontab for root”](http://askubuntu.com/a/554348/178692)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crontab error "No crontab for root"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/420290/crontab-error-no-crontab-for-root)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two methods to solve this situation, one which uses a system command, and another more manual method.

**Select-editor command**

Use the command:

```
select-editor
```

Which will give you another attempt at using the number-based system to select the default text editor.

**Manual Method:**

If it does not already exist, create the `.selected_editor` file for the user. This should be located in the user's home directory.

The contents should depend on which editor you prefer, for simplicity I'd recommend `nano`. To use `nano` the file should contain the line:

```
SELECTED_EDITOR=/bin/nano
```

To use the slightly more complicated/feature-rich editor `vim`, use:

```
SELECTED_EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim
```

Once you've specified your preferred editor, reload the `cron` service with:

```
service cron reload
```

At which point your user's `crontab -e` command should work as expected, with the chosen editor.

NOTE:This is the upstart method for restarting a service, which still works on 14.04, though using the systemd method `systemctl` is recommended for 16.04

Answer (score 3):

Check to see if `.selected_editor` exists in `/root/` if you are logged in as `root`, `/home/$USER` directory if you are not logged in as `root`.

If it does exist, then remove the file with one of the below commands:

- For `root` user:  `rm /root/.selected_editor`
- For non-`root` user:  `rm /home/$USER/.selected_editor`

Comment: Neither of these directories contain `.selected_editor` file. I also used `locate .selected_editor` command and output was empty.