# What is this editor that gets opened by crontab?

Tags: cron, text-editor

I want to edit crontab. It is supposed to be Vi, but it's not, as you can see:

```
root@euve252628:~# crontab -e

0

0 * * * * /var/www/vhosts/nevemind-what-webs/httpdocs/megacronstunde.php

?

:wq

?
```

Yes, it gave me a `?`.  And why does it give me a zero?

When I type a <kbd>q</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> - it quits. I need to know how to save, because it's not classic Vi.

Comment: Most likely `ed`: by default, it gives a character count (which in Debian based systems is typically `888` the first time, being the number of characters in the template "empty" crontab). If you're seeing a count of 0, you must have modified that. See [Crontab -e command not working properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802700/crontab-e-command-not-working-properly)

Comment: ed, man! !man ed: https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html

Comment: @juhist Rather than a comment this should be **the** answer.

Comment: While you usually want to just override `EDITOR` to something else, if you're interested in actually using ed, this is a great introduction: https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/actually-using-ed/

Comment: @justme, by the way, welcome to StackExchange! If you find an answer that best answers your question, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 65):

## That's `ed`

By default its prompt is the empty string. If you want to quit, just enter `q`. Don't prefix with `:`. If you have unsaved changes, it will reply with `?`. You can interpret that as "are you sure?", and confirm by commanding `q` again. By the way any command it doesn't understand will also cause it to reply `?`. That's the only error message it knows.

Its commands are what vim/vi/ex/sed is based on, so commands like `g/re/p`, `%s/vi/&m/g`, `1,3d`, `/pattern/,$d`, `w`, `q`, `wq` work just like vim.

Commands like `i`, `a`, and `c` go into insert mode. To leave insert mode and go back to command mode, just enter a line that has only a `.`. To "move" to another line, just enter the line number, an offset from the current line like `+2` or `-1`, or a regex as a command to go to that line. `.` means current line in command mode. You can use it to know where you're at. `$` means last line.

By the way, if you want to learn more about it, this being a GNU program in linux, most of its documentation is in `info ed` instead of `man ed`.

Here is an example session, with comments added (not accepted by ed):

```
$ ed
i                    # insert (on current line)
vi
.                    # end insert
%s/vi/&m/g           # substitute vi for vim globally in all lines
i                    # insert (on current line)
first line
.                    # end insert
$a                   # append on last line
last line
.                    # end insert
%p                   # print all lines
first line
vim
last line
2                    # move to line 2 and print it
vim
/line                # move forward to line matching /line/ and print it
last line
-1                   # move 1 line backwards and print it
vim
?line                # move backward to line matching /line/ and print it
first line
+1                   # move 1 line forward and print it
vim
g/line/p             # print lines matching /line/ (grep)
first line
last line
p                    # print (current line)
last line
.                    # move to current line and print it
last line
c                    # change (current line)
final line
.                    # end insert
%p                   # print all lines
first line
vim
final line
/vim/,$c             # change from line matching /vim/ to last line
that's all
.                    # end insert
%p                   # print all lines
first line
that's all
wq                   # write and quit
?                    # write what?
h                    # help with last error message
No current filename
wq                   # write and quit to check error message
?
H                    # help with all error messages
No current filename
wq                   # write and quit to check error message
?
No current filename
wq file.txt          # write file.txt and quit
22                   # wrote 22 bytes
```

EDIT: Like grawity mentions, more helpful error messages can be activated with `h` or `H`. Also, `,` rather than `%` in the range part of a command is the official way to refer to "all lines" in `ed`. In GNU `ed`, the possibility to use `%` for this is supported but not mentioned in the `info` manual. Use of `%` for all lines was apparently invented by `ex`, seemingly because, there, `,` means `.,.` rather than `1,$` like in `ed`.

## EDIT2: Setting a different editor

Like other answers mentioned, if you want to specify a different editor, you can do so by setting the `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` environment variables. The difference between the two is explained in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4861/189744).

You can do so like this if you want to set it for a single command:

```
EDITOR=vi crontab -e
```

or like this if you want all programs launched in the shell session to use it:

```
export EDITOR=vi
crontab -e
```

You can save the `export` in `~/.profile` or `/etc/profile`, depending if you want it to be a user or system setting for bash, respectively. That's the unix portable way to set the editor; you can do this in any distribution.

In Ubuntu, there is also the `update-alternatives` command. The current default editor can be seen with `update-alternatives --display editor`, and you can use `update-alternatives --config editor` to set it:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config editor
There are 4 choices for the alternative editor (providing /usr/bin/editor).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /bin/nano            40        auto mode
  1            /bin/ed             -100       manual mode
  2            /bin/nano            40        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/vim.tiny    10        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 3
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.basic to provide /usr/bin/editor (editor) in manual mode.
```

Comment: Modern versions know English error messages, you just need to use `h` to ask for them (or `H` to permanently enable it).

Comment: (Also, `%` appears to be an _ex_ invention. Officially _ed_ uses `,` to mean all lines, even though some versions accept `%` as well.)

Comment: This is *correct* but should also mention the `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` environment variables.

Comment: Most of the commands in `ed` are the same as in `vi`, except you don't have to press ":" first to get out of graphic editing mode. I learned Unix when "real programmers" didn't waste time using GUIs - an 80x25 "green screen" terminal works *nearly* as well as an IBM 029 card punch for editing, but not quite ;)

Comment: @chrylis `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` aren't really that relevant. The question was basically: *what is this editor, and how do I use it?* (what is this `0` and this `?`, and how do I save?).

Comment: But the *underlying* question is *WTF is going on here*?

Answer (score 39):

#### How to find out what this editor is

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. This suspends the editor and gives you a shell prompt. At the prompt, run `ps` to see what processes are running in this terminal.

```
bash-4.3$ crontab -e
1077
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 crontab -e
bash-4.3$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
26295 pts/10   00:00:00 bash
26297 pts/10   00:00:00 crontab
26298 pts/10   00:00:00 sh
26299 pts/10   00:00:00 ed
26302 pts/10   00:00:00 ps
```

`bash` is the original shell, `crontab` is expected, `sh` is another shell which must have been invoked by `crontab`, and `ps` is the running `ps` command. That leaves [`ed`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/ed.1.html) (provided by the [package of the same name](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ed)).

If you can't figure out how to quit the editor, you can kill it at this point, with `kill 26302` or `kill %1`.

#### What is ed?

Ed is an ancient editor, dating back from before monitors were a (commonplace) thing. It was designed for computers whose interactive output peripheral was a [teleprinter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter).

The `0` it displays at the beginning is the number of lines in the file. Evidently that's important information.

`?` means that ed didn't understand what you typed. Line printers are slow, so ed doesn't waste time and ink to display pointless information such as error messages. An old joke (I don't know the origin) goes:

> Ken Thompson has an automobile which he helped design. Unlike most automobiles, it has neither speedometer, nor gas gauge, nor any of the other numerous idiot lights which plague the modern driver. Rather, if the driver makes a mistake, a giant “?” lights up in the center of the dashboard. “The experienced driver,” says Thompson, “will usually know what’s wrong.”

If you feel inexperienced, you can issue the command `H` (all commands but one are a single letter (not counting data arguments), because who likes typing), and you'll get error messages. For example, if you just press <kbd>Enter</kbd>…

```
?
H
Invalid address
```

Clear, isn't it? (An empty line is the empty command — the one that isn't a single letter. The empty command moves to the next line and prints it. If you're at the end of the file, which is always the case in an empty file, there is no next line, so the address to which you requested to move is invalid.)

#### How to get another editor

The `crontab` command, like most commands that run a text editor, check the environment variables `VISUAL` and `EDITOR` (in that order) to decide which program to run, falling back to a system default. If either of these variables is set to `ed`, change it or remove it.

On Ubuntu (and Debian and others), the system default editor is `/etc/alternatives/editor`, which is managed through the [alternatives mechanism](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives). By default it picks the “best” editor that's installed, where “best” is defined by priorities set by package maintainers. Use [`update-alternatives`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/update-alternatives.8.html) to configure an alternative. You can display the available editors and their priorities with

```
update-alternatives --display editor
```

`ed` has the priority -100, whereas all the other “sensible” editors have a positive priority, so the only way it would be used by default is if no editor has been installed. A default installation of Ubuntu uses nano as the default editor, with priority 400. If the alternative has been set to `ed`, you can change it with

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

Comment: Gilles, Shouldn't *On Ubuntu (and Debian and others), the system default editor is /etc/alternatives/editor* be rephrased to *On Ubuntu (and Debian and others), the system default editor is /usr/bin/editor*?

Comment: quite comprehensive (except it doesn't mention EDITOR env variable? but maybe on purpose, so that people use the proper way to set it on the system via update-alternatives). Maybe change however : **`ps`** with **`pstree -sap $$`**  ? (easier to figure out which editor was launched, as it is now in a tree format)

Comment: @heemayl `/usr/bin/editor` is a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/editor`. The fact that applications call `/usr/bin/editor` is a detail that I skipped.

Comment: @OlivierDulac I do mention `EDITOR` and `VISUAL`. They are in fact the proper way to choose an editor since this is a user preference, not a system-wide preference. I prefer to stick to `ps` here to keep things simple.

Comment: @Gilles: Yep, i was referring to that very detail. +1 anyways.

Comment: @OlivierDulac Using `EDITOR` is also the portable way to set your editor across all distributions, user-wise (`~/.profile`) or system-wise (`/etc/profile`). I don't even have the command `update-alternatives` on my system, nor know what it's supposed to do technically.

Comment: @jimg:I know this is the portable way (that's why I commented about it, as I missed its mention the answer: as this is askubuntu and not unix.se, Gilles mentionned this Ubuntu-based additional info, which makes for a thorough answer).

Comment: "... computers whose interactive output peripheral was a line printer." A line printer was *not* an interactive device - it was a relatively high speed (and expensive) device for producing large amounts of printed output. You mean "a printing terminal with a keyboard", like a teletype (which could also work as a punched paper tape I/O device) or an IBM "golfball" typewriter.

Comment: _because who likes typing_ especially when the keys on the teletypewriters in use by AT&T had *really heavy keystrokes*, which strongly contraindicated lots of typing.

Answer (score 12):

From your question it seems like your default EDITOR is not `vim`, and you have problems with the current default editor.

The below command will set the default EDITOR to be `vim`

```
export EDITOR=vim
```

After setting the default editor to be `vim`, running `crontab -e` will use `vim` as your editor.

Notes:

1. If you prefer, you can choose different EDITOR as your default editor
2. If you want to set the default editor to `vim` permanently, you'll have to add the above command to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` or similar file.

Answer (score 4):

To use VI editor to edit crontab, use the below command.

```
EDITOR="vi" crontab -e
```

or, if you want to edit with another editor like gedit, nano, etc.,
just replace vi with the editor name.

Comment: Thanx a million! With the EDITOR="vi" crontab -e it works.

Comment: @gronostaj This is not the same as any other answer that has been posted here. Setting an environment variable for a single run of a single command is not the same as exporting it for all subsequent commands run from the current shell instance. [That answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/954755/22949) is useful for changing the setting permanently, but for controlling the editor per-run, this is the correct answer.

Comment: Indeed, knowing how to prepend environment variables on the command line is very important, as changing the variable permanently might be undesirable.  One of the subtle strengths of the *nix shells is the ability to do this so easily.